# Decimal to binary - For loop prints the binary in reverse mode

Tags: c

Background on what the code is supposed to do, vs what I am achieving.
So the dec2bin function is supposed to get the values/numbers decimal from the array dec_nums[]={0, 1, 77, 159, 65530, 987654321};

the function is supposed to convert the value to binary numbers and print it out.
the conversion is done correctly **however, it prints the binary backward.**

Can someone help me on figuring out what the problem is, or if there is another way to achieve the correct results?

```
int main() {
  int dec_nums[] = {0, 1, 77, 159, 65530, 987654321};
  int i;

  printf("=== dec2bin ===\n");
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(dec_nums) / sizeof(int); i++)
    dec2bin(dec_nums[i]);

  return 0;
}

void dec2bin(int num) {
  int saveNum = num;

  if (saveNum == 0) {
    printf("\nBinary Number of %d", saveNum);
    printf(" = 0");
  } else {
    int number;
    int i;

    printf("\nBinary Number of %i", saveNum);
    printf(" = ");
    for (i = 0; num > 0; i++) {
      number = num % 2;
      num = num / 2;

      printf("%i", number);
    }

    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: *Can someone help me on figuring out what the problem is* - the problem is pretty obvious. The algorithm you are using is calculating digits from right to left, but you are printing them from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

For bit fiddling *unsigned* types are preferrable, you avoid any kinds of problems with undefined behaviour due to under-/overflow.

Apart from, you can operate on bit masks:

```
for(unsigned mask = 1u << sizeof(mask) * CHAR_BIT - 1; mask; mask >>= 1)
{
    unsigned bit = (value & mask) != 0;
    // print it
}
```

`CHAR_BIT` is the value of bits within a char and comes from header `limits.h`, typically (but not necessarily) it is 8, with typically four bytes for `int`s you initialise the mask to `1 << 31` and further on shift it downwards until it reaches `1 << 0`, i. e. 1, which is the last value yet considered. Yet another shift moves the single bit set out of the `mask`, so you get 0 and the loop aborts.

Above code will print leading zeros, you might prepend another loop that simply shifts down until the first 1-bit is met if you want to skip them.

This variant starts at most significant bit; by `% 2` you always get the least significant bit instead – which is why you got the inverse order.

Side note: Getting length of an array is better done as `sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array)` – this avoids errors if you need to change the underlying type of the array...

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to write to bits into a char array, starting from the end of the array, the same way that we would do *by hand*.

Your `dec2bin` function would become (only minimal changes, with comments for added or changed lines):

```
void dec2bin(int num)


{
    // declare a char array of size number_of_bits_in_an_int + 1 for the terminating null
    char bin[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT + 1];
    char* ix = bin + sizeof(bin) - 1;  // make ix point to the last char
    *ix-- = '\0';                      // and write the terminating null
    int saveNum = num;
    if (saveNum == 0)
    {
        printf("\nBinary Number of %d", saveNum);
        printf(" = 0");
    }

    else
    {
        int number;
        int i;

        printf("\nBinary Number of %i", saveNum);
        printf(" = ");
        for (i = 0; num > 0; i++)
        {
            number = num % 2;
            num = num / 2;

            *ix-- = '0' + number;   // just write the bit representatin
        }
        
        printf("%s\n", ix+1);  //print the binary representation



    }




}
```

That is enough to get the expected result.